# How do you prove you're from the future?

Tags: time-travel

Let's say a time traveler from the year 2100 comes back to the year 2015.  He has a very important message: [horrible thing] is about to happen soon, and he wants to warn us so we can avoid/prevent it.  (Yes, this assumes a model in which "paradoxical causality" is not an issue.)  The problem is if he goes around saying, "I'm a time traveler from the future," no one's going to believe him.  They'd dismiss him as a crackpot.

So, he brings along proof, in the form of...?

This is actually a pretty tricky question, if we place two restrictions on it:

1. He does not have a "time machine".  His device sent him back without coming along with him, so he has no way to demonstrate that he's a time traveler by actually *demonstrating time travel*.  (Just as an side note, this is very much on purpose; he doesn't want knowledge of the mechanics of time travel to fall into the hands of people who might [use it for nefarious purposes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MakeWrongWhatOnceWentRight), and part of his plan is to actively sabotage scientific research that led to the development of time travel.)  The thing he used -- let's just call it a "time catapult" -- was able to send a small payload back in time, maybe comparable in volume to [a phone booth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096928/), certainly quite a bit less than [the interior of a car](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088763/).
2. He wants to get the issue of establishing proof of identity over with and out of the way as quickly as possible and move on to more important things, like averting future disasters.  This is a real issue; he can't go back arbitrarily far in time; the Temporal Frobulence Theorem shows that it becomes increasingly unsafe the further back you go; it's a bit of a stretch even to reach our time!

The two obvious candidates for proof are **future technology** and **knowledge of future events**. The first is tricky, because current technological advancement puts us perilously close to the boundaries of Clarke's 3rd Law: any sufficiently advanced technology is likely not to be easily recognizable as such, and anything *insufficiently advanced* would be likely to just look like someone working in his garage made a breakthrough in some field, and that's pretty cool and all, but it doesn't prove he's from the future.

The second is also tricky.  There are two major classes of unpredictable future events: natural and manmade.  Bringing official government records of earthquakes, hurricanes, etc. could certainly establish that he is who he says he is, but it would take a lot of valuable time for Mother Nature to furnish the proof.  On the other hand, if he predicts unpredictable manmade events, there are all sorts of potential troubles there.  Point out the time and place of a major crime?  Obviously, he was in on it; let's arrest him!  Produce a table of stock market closing values for the next month?  Well, he might be right for a day or two (coincidentally, of course!), but as soon as someone starts using the data he provides and attempting to profit by making trades based on it, the Butterfly Effect flutters in and destroys the accuracy of the data.

So, what would be the quickest, most efficient way for our unfortunate herald to establish beyond a reasonable doubt that he is a time traveler with accurate knowledge of future events, and at the same time, get enough people to listen to him so he can spread his doomsday message?

Comment: "part of his plan is to actively sabotage scientific research that led to the development of time travel" - Won't that cause a paradox?

Comment: @colmde Only if you accept the idea of paradoxes, which generally results from incorrectly conflating *time* and *causality* :)

Comment: I don't think I can answer this but I have an idea of birth certificates for any babies born month after the date he travels back to.

Comment: I would assert this, your positing this from a rather interesting point. You do not mention that the person knows that he did this because he has and it is recorded via some method. Meaning in simple terms, he is the first instance of time and he is influencing past instances of himself which is a problem because a past instance can not be the first instance. This can be solved if you allow time to NOT change your past. Instead it creates a new version of events. So it is a loop back, fork two instances, instance A is the original instance and instance B is the modified instance.

Comment: you state that paradoxical causality is not an issue, which would mean that the stock prices should not fluctuate when he provides this information...

Comment: @marcellothearcane No, what I mean is that, for example, killing your mother before you were born does not cause you to paradoxically vanish, because time is not the same thing as causality.  Your birth is already an event in the causal chain that led up to your current actions, and changing the timeline as part of your current actions does not alter that causal chain.

Comment: This seems to depend on the impending calamity. If a comet will hit Earth, simply point at the comet and we'll get it, without having to believe you're from the future. If [scientific thing we don't understand], then you'll have a hard time with that. You'd have to "invent" the science first, which might make a catch-22 in the story you're painting.

Comment: I strongly advise you from doing this - Time Crime Police will arrest you and believe me, I'd rather won't mess with them!

Comment: Why did I actually look up the temporal frobulence theorem...

Comment: A low-key demonstration would be the following. Say, you're on a bus and it's fairly crowded. You ask someone for a pen (because you have nothing to write with). You sketch a picture of an accident scene: fire truck, wrecked car on the median strip, police car, flashing lights, and caption it with the name of the two streets at the intersection, and give the pen back. 20 minutes later, as the bus approaches the intersection, you come onto the crash scene in the sketch. As you pass by, you hold up the picture in front of everyone and say: "I am from the future".

Answer (score 218, accepted):

He should predict [Solar Weather](http://www.swpc.noaa.gov/) and/or Solar Events.

Predicting Earth weather is a complex process, and he's introduced a new variable - himself.  And not that he'll have a huge effect, but you never know - the ripples of his arrival could be enough to throw off any predictions, creating doubt that he's authentic.

On the other hand, solar weather - the sun's activity - is also extremely difficult to predict, and is completely isolated from the time traveler's influence.  He can pull historical records from various space agencies and publish the results for the next week, in complete confidence that the data can't be effectively hidden or faked.

Comment: I like this a lot. It might not get a lot of attention from the general public, but it could absolutely alert some national leaders.

Comment: If someone did this, my first thought would be that they developed some extremely accurate way to predict the (solar) weather.  That seems unlikely, but it's a much more likely explanation than they are a time-traveller.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: that's a good point, but I think it applies to any single prediction.  I was originally thinking he should predict and track neutrino events from the sun - those should be entirely unguessable, as they're random - but I couldn't find a site or source where those are published.  An alternative would be to pick 2-3 different predictions, and publish all of them.  It's unlikely that someone would make simultaneous breakthroughs in multiple fields.

Comment: @DanSmolinske The problem with _truly_ random things is they might end up coming out different, depending on how the time travel mechanic works.

Comment: @Random832: That has some interesting implications for free will.  Might also invalidate lottery numbers and sports events.  If that was the case you'd need to take a completely alternate approach - hopefully our time traveler knows the physics well enough to decide which way to go with his/her proof.

Comment: I think it's a question of scale - a lottery number is probably _more_ likely to be randomly changed than a sports event - sports events depend on macroscopic physics and player skill, whereas lottery machines are deliberately chaotic - bumping into the lottery host earlier in the day might make them turn on the machine a second earlier or later and completely change the results.

Comment: @Random832: So thinking about this more, and I think solar weather is still likely to be ok over a decent timeframe.  It has to depend on the conditions throughout the entire star, and those aren't going to change significantly because of quantum-level events.  It gave me a better idea, though - what about measuring the randomness of distant stars?  Because you're effectively looking into the past, all the randomness has already occurred and is locked in when you time travel.  You would just need to find a study that measures pulsars or something around when you travel.

Comment: This might not get him to the right people in enough time.  If someone showed a random Joe these records, (1) Joe wouldn't care or be dismissive since Joe is not interested in Solar weather; and (2) even if he showed Joe, and Joe believed him, it would be a long time before Joe could get serious attention from the people who he needs to convince (he can't just call up the president - even if he could, he would be dismissed).

Comment: @Mikey: Start tweeting out hourly predictions of the conditions 24 hours from now at the various agencies.  Once 24 hours have passed, also post your original tweet, the actual conditions + the agency's prediction.  Wait for it to go viral, post the entire 2 week schedule.  After another couple of days, leverage that into air time and tell your story.

Comment: What about volcanic and seismic events? They can survive the butterfly effect for years right?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: If someone demonstrated this level of ability to predict chaotic events, I'd listen to him whether or not he claimed to be from the future. Come to think of it, he might achieve his goals more easily just by getting giga-rich, or claiming to be super-intelligent or psychic or alien or something.

Comment: @DanSmolinske Past randomness... that's brilliant!

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft:  Actually, it is not more plausible that he figured out a way to predict solar weather.  While time travel is a physical long-shot, it is not proven to be impossible.  Accurate prediction of a system as complex as solar weather, however, HAS been proven to be impossible (at least within our form of mathematics).  Not just hard, but impossible.

Comment: Solar weather would not actually be completely isolated from the time traveler's influence, the butterfly effect leads even tiny gravitational differences to lead to total unpredictability in fairly short order, see my answer [here](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/38404/298).

Comment: @DanSmolinske Pulsars are actually extremely regular, so when they are a few milliseconds off, you know something happened (like long gravitational waves). But maybe there's a supernova. That can be measured by the minute or whatever time accuracy the used telescope has, but it's extremely hard to predict even the month. Supernovas are rare, but the universe is very big and we can see supernovae even in distant galaxies.

Answer (score 489):

I'm going to suggest something rather different, given that he's from not far (2100) in the future.  All he will need to bring back is the names of his parents/grandparents.  With DNA testing of them and of him it would be possible to prove that he is their descendant, something impossible if he wasn't from the future.

Comment: Elegant and simple.  Welcome to the site rmoore

Comment: +1 because it will work even if the time machine sends him back in time naked, as long as he can remember where and when his grandparents lived.

Comment: Not one of my areas of expertise, but can we actually test to prove ancestry/decent? Or just degree of relationship, which is interpreted as parent/child when the relative ages match up?  For some reason I am thinking it is the later.  Still an excellent idea though.

Comment: +1 I like this, but I'd combine it with some sort of attention getter.  "DNA proof from the future" may take too long to gather interest - he has to gather all his grandparents, collect dna, etc, then get it verified again... but it works as a really nice proof once he has the government's attention.  It's also an interesting twist that he basically has to prevent his own birth (and possibly his parent's births) to prove he's real.

Comment: @Rozwel Yes, we can test for ancestry. You can test the mithocondrial DNA for mother-ascendancy (you will only have the same mithocondrial DNA as people who can trace relation through mothers). You can also test specific chromosomes and genes for ascendancy, since you get half from each parent. If the parents are already born, it is a piece of cake. If you can get all four grandparents, you can still get in the nineties percentile.

Comment: @Mindwin: I agree with Rozwel. Your reply starts with "yes", but nothing you've written really demonstrates "yes". (Mitochondrial DNA, for example, only shows that you share matrilineal ancestry with someone. It doesn't show that that someone actually *is* your matrilineal ancestor.)

Comment: @ruakh it is mithochondrial DNA coupled with gene mapping. You can prove relation to a person. Since you can prove relation to all your grandparents without a doubt, it would be impossible for you not to be their descendant, combined. but the whole analysis is too long for a comment. Should I expand rmoore answer in another answer?

Comment: @Mindwin yes, please!

Comment: But now that it's publicly known that little Johnny and Suzy are going to grow up, get married, and have kids, what if that knowledge turns them away from each other and you never exist? It wouldn't be the first time someone rebelled from their "destiny".

Comment: @DavidK: Since it's already established that he's trying to prevent the invention of time travel, that ship is already burned.

Comment: This is the site's first ever Great Answer badge. Congrats!

Comment: @DavidK he wrote at the beginning that "this assumes a model in which "paradoxical causality" is not an issue".

Comment: @Lohoris My analysis is posted: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/12720/353

Comment: "*With DNA testing of them and of him it would be possible to prove that he is their descendant,..*"  Right.  Unless, of course it turns out that you ***aren't***.  By some estimates, this is actually true about 1%-5% of the time.  And not only is this possibly *the worst* possible way to find this out, you also just lost the only chance you'll ever have to make a positive difference in the world.  "*Thanks, Mom!*"

Comment: And, IMHO, that's the hook to a much better story-line anyway ... ;-)

Comment: @RBarryYoung That would be pretty crazy and definitely make all the present-time people think you are crazy, I think that would be pretty easy to verify pre-time-travel just like any other data brought back.

Comment: With the same logic, wouldn't it be just as simple to present a sample of Carbon-14? Commonly this is used for radiocarbon dating and couldn't easily be faked. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon-14

Comment: This is only applicable to some time periods, only some people, and only some cases. It's quite error prone, among other things, some of the ancestor may simply refuse to consent to a DNA test. The biggest flaw is that if a geneticist today encountered such a "future person", they would conclude that either something went wrong with the test or it is a very strange coincidence, not that a physically dubious act has occurred. Besides, there is sometimes the matter of asking people to spend much time, money and effort on testing your samples because you believe you "came from the future".

Comment: @Superbest A lot of that like time period is in the question, and most of it would apply to any solution or generalization as well. Things like solar data or a sports almanac aren't going to do much good in the 1100s either. As for the flaw mentioned that's going to be a part of any verification process whether it's winning every state's lottery, predicting where an item will appear or anything else early responses will be along the lines of tester error/contamination, or improbable coincidence. In this case at least it's a rather well understood testing process and repeatable/verifiable.

Comment: @rmoore The OP does say the travel is from 2100 to "today". You have to go back centuries before an almanac becomes useful, but practical high resolution genotyping was a pipe dream even 20 years ago. Even today, 23andme does not ship to many countries. It is also much easier to convince someone to simply check the newspaper for sports matches (or stock prices, or weather) you predict than to ask them to do a bunch of involved molecular biology for something that they already believe to be impossible.

Comment: My understanding of today's DNA testing is that they can verify kinship, not relationship. In other words, given samples of a man and his son, they cannot tell who is the son and who is the father. Further, they might even say they are brothers, if the results vary enough.

Comment: How in the world is he going to convince anyone to do an expensive DNA test between two poor innocent citizens and some random lunatic who claims they're his great grandparents?

Comment: Some of the replies are correct in stating that DNA tests show only kinship with certain probability. However, it IS possible to prove the descendancy this way.

Keep in mind that your parents are (hopefully!) not related closely to each other. Your grandparents as well. Therefore, you have to compare their DNA with your own, and also - here's the key step! - with each other's.

If it turns out that you are closely related both to person A and person B, but person A is not closely related to person B, the only logical explanation is that you are their descendant.

Comment: Or you could just have randomly acquired the same genetic pattern, like in that terrible movie Jupiter Ascending

Comment: I joined this community just to upvote your answer as not voting it up would have been sin-ish on my part

Comment: This is not a future-proof way. We may expect gene editing to become easy like genetic testing. In some years you might be able to fake your ancestors. Gene editing in human cells was reported in 2015 https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs13238-015-0153-5

Comment: @FinnÅrupNielsen The future existence of gene editing merely makes the task easier. The traveler can be made to appear as the descendant of a currently powerful world leader, even if not true. The "now" science wouldn't be aware of the "fact" of gene editing, and thus "prove" the ancestry of the traveler. Believing that is DNA was edited would require believing he came from a time when that is possible, thus "proving" his time-travel claim. Proving ancestry isn't the goal, proving the time-travel is.

Answer (score 192):

There is one more very convincing thing he can bring from the future: actual copies of items from the present. If someone came up with an aged Mona Lisa, the bones of Barrack Obama and the Tiffany Yellow Diamond, I doubt his claims of coming from the future would be ignored.

Now how he can come up with these items in the future is the subject of another story, but I am assuming he isn't just some mad scientist who wants to right some wrongs in the past, but he is an exponent of a troubled species that NEEDS to prevent a catastrophic future, therefore his experiment can be outfitted with some inconsequential items as those described above.

Comment: The bones of someone living - where an exact DNA match can be made - seems a lot more reliable than the much-upvoted DNA-relationship answer.  Both have the problem of being spoofed through cloning methods, though.

Comment: That's why you bring some other rare items. I'm fairly sure there's no way to clone a huge diamond and the "copy" of Mona Lisa can be dated to show that it's 100 years older than the "original".

Comment: Would be interesting if time responds by whipping the contemporary "originals" out of existence at the time of the jump, to "compensate" (and this happens in some fictional narratives). Whoops, sorry, Mr President; my, you're looking rather _limp_ today...!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree, it would be interesting. However, i find it very hard to figure out a coherent system where such rules would apply. Would the atoms that form the time traveler's body be "removed" from the past? What about subparticles? What about radiation? I find it easier to concieve that the objects are simply "injected" in the past. Still, good point.

Comment: @Tibos: I concur

Comment: "mad scientist who wants to *write* some wrongs in the past" I can't tell if meant *right* from the context or not.

Comment: Those things are hard to get. "May I have the Mona Lisa please? It's to prove that I'm from the future. No, you won't get it back, but that won't matter because as soon as I change the timeline you won't exist anymore."

Answer (score 117):

**The critics provided the proof themselves**

Before he travels back in time, he uses his machine to send along a "parcel of proof" to some point in time after his own arrival. He can then predict that this parcel will arrive out of thin air at a specified moment. By being an extraordinary event, this boosts his credibility.

The clincher however, is that the parcel contains recordings of his stay in the days following the arrival of the parcel. Things which he buried at a secret location and retrieved himself in the future. There could be letters the sceptical inhabitants have sent to themselves, video recordings of people he has met telling how they have finally been convinced that he is a traveller from the future, accounts of the many random things in their lives such as the timing of a sudden onset of rain that ruined their crop, accounts of a kid that fell and broke his leg or of where misplaced items were finally found.

Story-wise this gives you an excuse to introduce the supporting characters in more depth. You can, if you like, arrange for a circle of true believers while keeping the world at large indifferent to his claims. For the reader, the point after which he has buried the parcel marks when the outcome of events starts being uncertain again, possibly building tension in the story. Perhaps we'll also see some dramatic scene where the traveller tries to retrieve the package again, to add a warning to himself about trouble occuring.

Comment: Presumably this only works if the critics existed in his timeline previous to him heading back.  Depending on the time travel paradigm, it might not be possible.

Comment: As per the question, the time traveller is not going to travel further back than he already has, so he can't wipe out their existence if they were born when he arrived.

Comment: Sorry - I don't mean existed at all.  I mean that they existed *as critics*.    Let's say Bob is TT's greatest critic, but he's only a critic in a timeline where TT has gone back in the past and claimed to be from the future.  In TT's original timeline, there (presumably) was no time travel, so while Bob was alive, he wasn't a critic and there's no evidence of this nature.

Comment: This approach assumes that whatever I do now, the world still ends up in the same state it was in before I came back.   Which completely invalidates my trip.  If we go with the OPs intention that we cause the time line to diverge, then the cache I bury never makes it to the place I came from, because that future never occurs in the timeline I bury it in.

Comment: @Rozwel aren't you perhaps assuming that when this reality alters, EVERY thing changes...couldn't it be that certain timelines may or may not be affected by the time traveler... Thus there is still a chance that this proof could play out?

Comment: @Rohan No, I don't think so.  My original timeline may still exist as a parallel to the one I am trying to change.  But for my parcel to reach me on that time line, it had to result from me coming back to bury it.  So obviously I either failed to cause the desired changes, implying that time is immutable and all is predestined.  Or I in fact caused the original timeline by coming back in the first place, there by causing a paradox loop.

Comment: Even if the method is possible, if you have to convince more than a handful of people, it's going to be difficult to arrange that. We have no specifics as to what organization the traveler is associated with. If this is post-apocalypse, or at least post-[horrible thing], their resources are probably limited.

Comment: I really like this solution because each critic could demand the exact proof they want... timey wimey... stuff!

Comment: Skeptics want repeatable events under their own control. They'll want to chose the time, object, and place, then ask you to perform again.

Answer (score 86):

The problem with knowledge of the future is that as soon as you make one alteration the future starts to change. Knowledge of one lottery result would be fine, but results after that would rapidly become unpredictable again.

One of the comments is absolutely right though, start by winning the lottery, just send yourself back with a bit of money and a false identity.

Additionally send yourself back in time to shortly before a major disaster and use your lottery winnings to avert it and to invest in a number of companies that you know will grow large. You can also bring back a suitable list of inventions to use your lottery seed money to start working from.

With that level of money and influence you can then not try to convince people, just get them to do what you want without ever mentioning being a time traveler.

If you really want to convince people though then use natural events that will still happen predictably. For example if you know a major earthquake is going to strike new york at 9:13am on Wed 4th August then use your money to place billboards warning people and to place relief shelters and supplies ready.

That will get people listening.

Comment: Good point.  A time traveler depending on the actions of others is likely a paradox waiting to happen.  It would make sense if they tried to stay low key.

Comment: Using money and influence without mentioned when you came from also avoids the problem Rozwel brought up - if you're trying to prevent the development of time-travel technology, demonstrating that it is possible is a good way to ensure people *will* work on it and eventually figure it out.

Comment: "Knowledge of one lottery result would be fine, but results after that would rapidly become unpredictable again." One thing a visitor from the future could do to predict many lottery results without affecting them is to publicly publish an encrypted document with, for example, a whole month's worth of results. No one can read the document at first, but they can see that it's there and not changing. Only after the month has passed does the visitor publish the decryption key. Since the document was published publicly and unchanged, everyone can see that the visitor had all those results upfront.

Comment: And the person drawing the lottery balls spends a few more minutes on their lunch break one day because they read the article about someone making this claim, and that's enough to make the result randomly change.

Comment: @Random832 Yep, butterfly effect is in action here. Results would be stable for 1 or 2 draws I expect but they would start diverging rapidly after that.

Comment: @TimB Also, it goes without saying that _winning_ a lottery that was not won in the original timeline even once is going to have a profound effect on the subsequent jackpot pool size, how many people buy it (many people only buy, or buy more tickets, when the jackpot is high), etc.

Comment: @NickChammas - I wonder if with a sufficiently weak encryption algorithm and enough computing power, he could generate "decryption keys" after the fact that decrypt the document to whatever the winning numbers happened to be. Probably harder to do if he's predicting dozens of lotteries, but perhaps possible for a fraudster to do if he were only predicting a few.

Comment: @Johnny  Generating a key to get the desired clear text is theoretically possibly with any algorithm.  The key to most (all?) of our current encryption standards is that there is no known way to predict such a key from a given cypher text.  Meaning you would have to just try keys repeatedly until you found one to give the desired outcome.  The probability of success in such an attempt is extremely low.  Of course if our traveler brought a computer back with him, he may have the processing power to pull it off in a reasonable timeframe.  But that kind of proves the point in itself...

Comment: "Results would be stable for 1 or 2 draws I expect" -- is there a basis for that estimate, or just what seems fun for a story? Is it a solved problem in physics, whether or not the arrival of a 70kg time traveller in (say) London is likely to affect the result of a lottery draw in (say) New York 24 hours later? If you can quantify the sensitivity of lottery draws to butterflies, then you'll know, but much of the attraction of mechanical random processes lies in the fact that we don't know in what ways they're sensitive to the environment (while remaining apparently fair) ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Well, I was thinking 1 to 2 draws in one country. Not worldwide. (i.e. over the course of a week or two here in the uk). Considering the lottery draw is deliberately a highly chaotic system then any modification at all on the inputs will change the output. That means that isolation from the ripple effects of changing time will be hard to maintain. Especially once you change time significantly by winning the previous lottery.

Comment: @TimB: sure, but why do you say "a week or two to cover the UK" instead of saying for example "the speed of sound in the earth", as being the rate at which the butterfly effect propagates a degree of difference sufficient to re-randomise the draw? We know it's highly chaotic but I don't know whether we can put a number on it (other than authorial fiat, ofc).

Comment: @SteveJessop Because there is no way to put a number on it, so all we can do is make reasonable guesses as to how long it will take for the effects of your actions to modify the next draw. Arriving and buying a lottery ticket will probably not have time to change the first draw after you arrive (particularly if you arrive just before the draw is taken), but the probability then starts reducing rapidly for each subsequent draws and you cannot 100% guarantee the result of any draw after that first one.

Comment: In other words all I said is that you can only have high confidence in your knowledge of the first draw result. All draws after that first one have a significant and increasing chance of being different.

Comment: I don't mean to interrogate you, but it seems you're highly confident that the lottery machine isn't *so* sensitive and chaotic that 70kg of extra mass in a particular place in London will affect (e.g. by its gravity) which balls are selected, but there's no basis in physics and mechanics for being so confident. We simply don't know enough about the machine and so the worldbuilder is free to speculate. Reasonable summary? ;-)

Comment: @NickChammas I can see a couple of problems. One, which was already mentioned, is butterfly effect. The second, is that somebody can create a document that has varied answers based on what your key is. Third, is that you might be part of the lottery company.

Answer (score 86):

I read a saying somewhere: "If it doesn't have wires sticking out of the case, it's not cutting-edge."

I think carrying 2100-era technology would be a clincher.  It's one thing to build a device that holds 500x as much data as any hard drive in existence.  It's much harder to package it up in a sleek, friendly interface that's clearly gone through a dozen rounds of feedback and redesign.

Say somebody shows up at the front gates of the White House with a smart-matter robot with smooth, seamless AI, the ability to 3D-print insanely complex objects out of electricity and dirt, and a demonstrated ability to calculate at 3000 petaflops/second (100x faster than the current fastest supercomputer).  You can't dismiss that as "something a guy built in his garage."  You can't even dismiss it as a "secret government or corporate project."  The construction of such an artifact requires too many breakthroughs in too many independent fields.

Heck, I suspect if you took an iPad back to 1995 and handed it over to a team of engineers and asked them, "Future or Nifty?" they'd come back within a few days and say, "definitely future."

So I think it's a more interesting question if you deny the possibility of bringing anything but information back.  My solution (riffing off the 'solar weather' answer): use information that has already been generated, but hasn't reached us yet.  Random data encoded in electromagnetic waves still flying towards Earth.

For example, the semi-random "hiccups" in the rotation speed of pulsars.

To be thorough, you'd want data of several different phenomena.  If all you have is microquake data from pulsars, or the coordinates and times of supernovae... any one thing could be dismissed as "oh, they just made a breakthrough in predicting X."  But making breakthroughs in X, Y, Z, and W?  Much harder.

[Neutron star - Rotation (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star#Rotation)

Update: Looks like DanSmolinsk had the same idea.

Comment: If you take an iPad to 1995, good luck finding WiFi or cell coverage. You better pack some apps with offline functionality.

Comment: @VictorJalencas Bring a modern laptop as well, use ad-hoc WiFi and Ethernet. They had 10BaseT Ethernet in 1995, which your laptop should still be compatible with.

Comment: @immibis Try to get at least a 56k modem though...

Comment: And the services that go with the online apps will all be non-existent! :)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I'd imagine you can get some sort of bridge between Ethernet and 56k in 1995. (I've never heard of a 56k modem with an Ethernet interface, but you could at least get a computer with one of each to act as a bridge)

Comment: Given this evidence I'd want to contest the "time-traveller" hypothesis with (a) the hypothesis that the artifact is the work of aliens who have been tracking earth technology and simulated something slightly ahead of it, (b) same thing, Illuminati. I mean, I work in tech, and I have no idea where a secret conspiracy would keep all the infrastructure required to be 50-100 years ahead of the game in terms of technology produced on production lines. But sufficiently advanced tech could perhaps produce a one-off that *appears* to be futuristic commodity tech.

Comment: @immibis for what it's worth, in 1998 or so, I had a dual 56K modem thingy with Ethernet that 3COM was selling as a poor man's ISDN line.  If you had two ISP accounts and were really lucky, it could sometimes even bond them so you got ~112 Kbps

Comment: The real question is, what would an engineer of 1915 think of the iPad?

Comment: This doesn't work - You could have been given the technology by an alien from a more technologically advanced world.

Comment: More likely result of having such advanced computer is that he'd be killed and his device stolen, and used to break crypto, steal bitcoins etc. Or, in more beneficial case, just kidnapped and used by some government and used to spy / sabotage other rival governments.

Answer (score 53):

An easy solution would to have the time traveler use the [NIST randomness beacon](https://beacon.nist.gov/home), or some variant in your story.

The randomness beacon outputs a random number, signed by its key, every minute.  By definition, the value of the number is unknown until its time passes, and is immutable after that time.

Before leaving, the time traveler simply looks in the beacon archives, and prints off/memorizes the beacon values near the time he's traveling to.

All the time traveler has to do is publish the results of the beacon for some times after the time he travels to.  For example, he could publish the next hour's worth of beacon values right after he arrives.  Once that time passes, everyone can see that the time traveler indeed knows the future.

Furthermore, one doesn't have to worry about the butterfly effect with the beacon!  Because the NIST beacon/similar beacons use a radioactive source as the random number generator part, previous events have no effect on future events.

From a [hackday article](http://hackaday.com/2014/12/19/nist-randomness-beacon/) explaining it:

> More esoterically, one could use the Randomness Beacon to prove that something is newer than a certain date by including a recent Beacon entry. As of this writing, the values for December 31, 2014 are all still up in the air, so I can’t possibly write one of them down yet. But from Jan 1, 2015 and on, it’s trivial to do so. So if I get a bunch of t-shirts made with the midnight value from December 31, it’s absolutely verifiable that I got them made in the new year. In short, you could use the Beacon as a not-older-than dating scheme.

Comment: Definitely a cool thing!

Comment: Alternatively, this could be interpreted as the NIST beacon being fake (e.g. preproduced), and you being an insider.

Comment: I'm not sure the beam works for this purpose.  The answer seems to be assuming that the random numbers generated are pretty robust in the face of whatever microscopic changes your appearance in the timeline makes.  The NIST describes a quantum entanglement setup that I'm still trying to wrap my head around, but it could get knocked off course by tiny quantum effects, sending them off to generate a completely different set of numbers.  You'd have to run some time travel experiments beforehand.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann, that is a hole, but the beacon outputs combined with some of the other answers here could make it more robust.  It's possible that there's an insider, but the probability gets lower when the "NIST insider" also knows what the stock market is going to do, etc.

Comment: @BryceAnderson: indeed, inventing time travel would let us test whether radioactive decay events are "fixed points in time" or not (I think that's the terminology from Doctor Who, correct me if I'm wrong). If they aren't, then the time traveller has nothing (and, indeed, all time travel will be to a rapidly-diverging alternate history, with the result that trying to "change" it could be a moot point if it's very different from what you remember anyway). If they are, though, then the scheme works. Furtunately this is WB, so the author can just rule on unknowns in physics :-)

Comment: ... the worst case scenario for a time traveller hoping to change the past, is a Michael Moorcock short story *Flux*, in which the traveller discovers there is no continuous history, just an infinity of random, unrelated moments, one of which just so happened to contain a person with a working time machine and a false memory of having lived a life through continuous history to that moment.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann, while a normal person might consider the beacon to be fake, it should provide very strong proof to those familiar with the beacon and how it works. Depends on who we're trying to prove to, I guess.

Answer (score 51):

Bring copies of future expensive movies, think *Avengers 4*. It's not plausible to fake such.

As a bonus, bring additional material, think interviews and making-of documentaries.

Comment: I think there needs to be some explanation around this answer... it is not impossible to create movies in the present day, and making copies of it is not more difficult. How will you prove that it is expensive and also from the future?

Comment: @MichaelLai it imagine making a movie as expensive as Avengers 4 in secret. It's not plausible. It's easy to tell if a movie is expensive... just look at the special/visual effects.

Comment: I like it! If you bring one movie back, maybe you found some way to secretly make an expensive movie. But if you bring 1000 blockbuster movies back, you've created something like 10 to 100 billion dollars worth of material. It would be hard to explain that away.

Comment: Reading this now, feels strange.

Comment: @DickieBoy because release is close?

Comment: @Tshepang indeed, When this post was made, Avengers 2 was just coming out(i think). If they were to go come from the future. The full series of MCU films would be an awesome thing to bring back.

Answer (score 44):

Predict astronomical events. If you can supply coordinates and magnitude of supernova explosions, neutron stars oscillations or other similar events, it would be impossible for you NOT to be from the future.

You could be mistaken for an FTL space traveler, but if you bring enough data points from disparate directions, Occam's razor would work in your favor, and between time travel and FTL spaceman, time traveler would be chosen, because it would have less assumptions.

Since the astronomical events came from random points in the sky, it would be impossible to exist one place in the universe where these events could've been seen before being seen on earth (due to lightspeed limitations, it would need to exist one point in space nearer ALL events than Earth - assuming space is quadridimensional like in Einstein's relativity), and that there would be one observer with FTL capability at that point willing to come to earth to lie about being a time traveler.

Just being a bona fide time traveler would have less assumptions.

Comment: This is great, because it would be impossible to fake the information and your existence couldn't change the results. I think the problem with this is that you'd have to wait for all of these events to take place.

Comment: Actually, there are plenty of supernovae that can be used, but they are extra-galactic so non-specialists are unaware of them. That makes this a very robust and simple solution.

Comment: There is no difference between a FTL space traveler and a time traveler, is there?

Comment: @corsiKa depends on your cosmology. A time traveler has the advantage of being able to be both (if FTL is available in his epoch), but the FTL traveler would still be [bound to the geodesics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity#Geodesics_as_curves_of_stationary_interval)

Comment: Ouch I don't quite understand that article. Is that basically saying I'm bound in four dimensions in how far I can travel? So for any given time I want to travel, there's a sphere emanating from me that I have to stay within?

Comment: @corsiKa the FTL traveler is still bound by the inexorable passing of time. He leaves Earth for Alpha Centauri. Travel ETA is 4 hours. He spends 2 days (48 hours) at the sulphur beaches of AC, and returns to Earth. He is now 56 hours after he departed. He cannot "gain" time by FTL travel, thus he is bound by the geodesics even if he moves faster than light. but that `depends on your cosmology`.

Comment: Certainly if I'm forced to stipulate interstellar FTL travel in order to discard the possibility of an earth-bound phone-box time machine, then I'm going to accept time travel in some form either way. Given FTL travel and some careful preparation it does seem likely that the FTL traveller actually could bring us information from our future anyway. So in considering FTL I'd be wondering whether this "person with information from the future" is *telling the truth*, which the traveller is going to have to deal with anyway regardless of what proofs he can make of being a time traveller ;-)

Comment: An FTL space traveler **is** a time traveler.

Comment: @Mindwin Our traveller spends 4 hours travelling to Alpha Centauri in our inertial frame of reference. But if he picks a different frame of reference for the return 4 hour journey, he can get back before he left. And relativity tells us that there's no privileged frame of reference, so there's no reason why the traveller has to use the same frame of reference for both journeys.

Comment: How random are those events though?

Answer (score 34):

I feel like a strong approach could be to provide solutions for various problems of that era. Things that the top people in their respective fields have been trying to solve for many years with little to no progress. By convincing them, their feedback should influence others.

- Solving (with proofs) the remaining six [Millennium Prize
  Problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems) simultaneously would blow the minds of mathematicians.
- Bringing back documentation of cures
  for various forms of cancer/diseases could convince the medical
  field.
- As so on with physics, space, etc.

The biggest benefit off of this is that multiple field breakthroughs will cause so much world-wide impact that you'll end up with proof people can experience. It would be hard to say you're just a savant because research by the world's best couldn't do it either and they're specialists.

A few feasible issues are

- The amount of time it would take to provide this documentation and
  have people take it seriously. (If you could kick-start your first
  breakthrough, the others could accelerate.)
- Whether or not these solution were indeed solved within the timeframe we're limited to.

Comment: I'm not sure how well this would work. Cures for diseases would take a while to work itself out; as for proofs, the issue is that the proofs you see in 2100 are likely to build on a lot of background that just isn't there now. The ABC conjecture had a claimed proof released in 2012, which *still* hasn't been fully checked by the math community (because the author had for some years gone off in his own direction, which meant that no one else had the background to fully understand the proof). If the traveller presents a proof from the textbooks of 2100, no one will likely understand it.

Comment: Also, it's unlikely that all six of the Millennium problems would be solved by 2100.

Comment: @cpast You only take about 30 to 40 different courses in a bachelor's degree, many of which aren't related to your field of study. You could pack a small library of 50-100 books from 2100 and give someone a complete 4 year degree. I'm pretty sure the brightest minds in our world could understand it.

Comment: Nice one. Following this line of thinking, you can easily pack a vast amount of human knowledge from the year 2100 that, including sequences of text books back to present day, all into a portable memory device. Carefully research current day technology so as to be able to access it electronically as fast as possible. Important side effects: 1) Utterly changing the future. 2) Possibly provide technological means to more easily deal with the impending disaster.

Comment: @corsiKa As a naysayer, I must say that if the "facts" from the future don't match the strong beliefs from now, the "brightest minds" will reject the texts.  (global warming for example)  "But, you have to be dead.  The Earth will have been made inhospitable by 2040!"  (or whatever)

Comment: Possibly 5 remaining millennium problems, depending on wether or not the Indian mathamethician who claimed to solve the Riemann hypothesis was right or not.

Answer (score 32):

A copy of a newspaper. Surely in the future he would have access to historical documents and newspapers among them. A copy of a national newspaper from  several days in the future that hadn't even been written yet would surely  be some kind of proof. Especially if it remarked on an event that hadn't yet occurred.

Comment: and contained the lottery results...

Comment: The key to making this work, I think, is to show up, say "this is next Thursday's newspaper", and (with witnesses) lock it up somewhere that none of them can access before then.  (Safe-deposit box with key escrow?  Something like that.)  Then next Thursday you all march on over there to retrieve it.  If anybody *looks* at it before then you risk butterfly effect, but you have to establish its "identity".

Comment: Sadly, even if no one sees it, it could be changed.  The headline could be, "Will this be our predicted headline?" or even "Correct Horse Battery Staple".  The people who make the paper in question will no doubt pick up on this news-worthy occurrence and report on it.

Comment: @MBurke It depends on which model of time travel you're using.  I personally like the fixed-timeline model, in which the newspaper would end up being the same no matter what happened, because it already happened that way!

Comment: I would not take the entire newspaper, because predicting major future events could lead to changing behavior influencing those events. Just use newspaper clippings of events just relevant enough to be mentioned in a newspaper, and that have 100% accuracy (no weather reports): e.g. minor earthquakes. Even if you include man-made events that theoretically could be changed with foreknowledge (e.g. a filmstar marriage), that likelihood is small because the time traveller is not believed **yet**.

Comment: Locking it up without anyone seeing it is just going to prove you are an impressive stage magician who can swap Thursdays newspaper with one locked up in an apparently secure place without anyone noticing.

Comment: This works really well if he only tells, say, the team of scientists he needs to convince, rather than announcing it to the media at large.  That way he doesn't affect the paper (unless one of the team leaks it, in which case, he's probably the mad scientist that causes Horrible Thing to begin with).

Comment: As armb says, unfortunately for the time traveller, stage magicians pull this kind of thing all the time (I remember Dynamo doing a newspaper headline, and Derren Brown the lottery results). Obviously, they cheat, but that's not the point, the time traveller is still competing with them and he needs to be more convincing than they are to his target audience, whoever that is. I will note, though, that neither of those magicians used a public notary to lodge their sealed predictions, so that *might* be sufficient to convince people who trust notaries (such as lawyers and courts).

Comment: Dynamo did something similar to this using a [CD recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaR23uZjW_Q). So people can simply dismiss it as 'magic'. (BTW the trick wasn't very good)

Comment: He could have just had publisher collaborating with him. I would not take this as proof

Answer (score 29):

I wouldn't actually try to prove I was from the future.  I would focus on proving the event would take place.  If I couldn't prove it, I would focus on getting the appropriate response in place via a subtle, roundabout way.  For example, if the event was an asteroid collision, you forge an email to an astronomer from a trusted colleague telling him where to point his telescope.  If the event was a terrorist attack, you send the authorities anonymous tips and maybe even plant some clues yourself.

This might be interesting in contrast to previous more drastic attempts that failed.  Maybe previous time travelers assassinated Hitler too early, which caused something even worse to happen, so you agree to be his bodyguard, but send some key piece of information to Alan Turing to help him build his enigma-cracking machine that he never managed to complete in your timeline.  Then you fake Hitler's suicide once it's safe to do so.

Or maybe something not so subtle.  In your timeline, Saddam Hussein eventually manages to detonate 3 nuclear bombs in America.  After several more subtle attempts, you plant some WMD intelligence way before the event, but that's still not enough to get the U.S. government to intervene, so in desperation you perpetrate the 9/11 attacks.

Comment: +1, You **cannot** prove you're from the future *beyond reasonable doubt*. Do what you came to do, don't just talk about it.

Comment: Oh here we go with the Saddam Hussein fantasies.

Comment: Sounds farfetched.  But, on the other hand, it doesn't sound implausible.

Comment: That's sort of the point.  Any averted future event naturally sounds like a crazy conspiracy theory.

Answer (score 22):

You mention the option of either unpredictable natural or man-made events. If you publish a table of stock prices, then the future will change based on how people use them. What about a table of things people cannot change?

Use **daily weather information** for a few weeks in the future. You can publish precise highs, lows, conditions for a variety of locations around the globe. Weather is something that is always difficult to predict, and having knowledge of what will happen will not change the outcome. Additionally, you won't have to wait for natural disasters like earthquakes to take place. After a day or two of accurately predicting weather across the globe, people should either believe that you are from the future or are the best meteorologist in all of history!

Comment: This would work very well if the past is *completely* immutable; but if that's the case, what's the point of trying to change history? If history can be changed, then by a classic butterfly effect, the traveller would affect global weather patterns just by walking around and breathing. Your weather information might be good for a while, particularly for more distant locations, but not indefinitely.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit You're correct that the traveler's presence would affect weather patterns on the long-term. However, you only need to predict the weather conditions enough so that people believe you are from the future, and the presence of one extra person is not going to have a significant impact on that short of a scale.

Comment: I believe this draws a thin line between "time-traveler" and "talented weather man with access to weather monitoring technology". Could the weather information be strong enough for a long enough period of time to provide evidence that this person wasn't just paying attention to the weather patterns? I feel like even if it was convincing enough to go against the weather man theory, how it would it go for the time-traveler theory? Not being a weather man does not a time traveler make.

Comment: @DanDavis: If you have a backpack full of equipment in your phone booth, you could carry *a lot* of weather records just on microfilm, let alone digital storage media. But it's true that the authorities would take a lot of convincing your special weather knowledge derived from time travel and not, say, highly advanced [groundhogs](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107048/).

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit Time traveling weather groundhogs may just be the solution.

Comment: Since nobody seems to be mentioning it: there are hundreds of earthquakes that occur every day, most just don't register on a human scale, but they do occur, and to correctly identify all of them would be astronomically unlikely without foreknowledge.

Comment: Since you're trying to establish prescience, stock market prices are an excellent choice. What you do is remove the stock names, and (for instance), add in an offset. The offset could be included as the 23d item in the list, which is then ranked in numerical order. Since the list is very long (~9000 stocks on NASDAQ) the odds against producing an accurate list are astronomical, yet backing out the individual stock prices would be extremely difficult. Really, any encryption technique with the key held in safekeeping will do.

Answer (score 22):

The time traveler should set new video game speed run records using glitches not currently known. For instance, there are currently still large, active communities uncovering new methods in Nintendo 64 games such as Zelda: Ocarina Of Time.

This is a non-violent method which involves no money or physical objects. It  minimizes introducing variables mentioned above through lottery/stock manipulation as subsequent events are not based on the outcome of the prior event (i.e., Glitch 2 in Game B will not change upon completing Glitch 1 in Game A).

I am sure this method would garner the time traveler enough media attention and credibility to then springboard to convincing the public on whatever "serious" issue as at hand.

As I'm typing this, it just occurred to me that this was the plot of "The Wizard" when they introduced Super Mario Brothers 3 and the one competitor knew how to get to the early warp zone.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy this -- it would be difficult to prove that the traveller had not been in communication with the game developers. The developers might have been aware of the glitches and simply not made them public. Alternatively, the traveller might have just spent a *really long time* playing Zelda or whatever -- no special knowledge from the future required.

Comment: I think this is a pretty interesting and novel solution.  I like that it wouldn't really have any significant effects.  I think credibility would be handled by using multiple games from a wide variety of developers and time periods.  Plus it's just so crazy it has to work.

Comment: I like it.  Welcome to the site todd

Comment: Really novel idea.  I like it.  I'd suggest having prepared glitches/speedrun for games that have yet to come out, too.  That way you can post a complete speedrun and/or demonstrate all the glitches on the very day it comes out.

Comment: @bobson that could be counterproductive.  If I am building a game, and I see videos of someone exploiting glitches in other games to do things that weren't intended, I am likely to recheck my own work to make sure they can't do the same thing there.  The more such glitches are exposed, the more likely I am to find something to change in my game.  Point being that at least some of the glitches he practiced/recorded will no longer be there when my product releases.

Comment: It's an interesting approach, but this could just as easily be explained by someone who has been holding off on sharing crazy new tricks. You also need to be *good* at said games. I know how 0-star Super Mario 64 works, but that doesn't mean I can complete a 0-star run.

Answer (score 19):

We can already store enormous volumes of information in a pocketable medium.  Bring a petabyte of (his current) Wikipedia on his pocket reader.

In so many TV shows and movies, the lone traveller has to do everything from scratch, and his limited resources is the main source of making it interesting.

Why not have a well-researched plan in place? The catapult to the target past might be a one-shot, but going back a week or month is easy and just a couple years is routine.

They can grow their resources and make plans in a small time loop near home: each jump back improves upon the planning and size and effectiveness of the organization.

They can become very wealthy and politically powerful, and recruit talent from the brightest of the population, seemingly (from the outside in normal time) by a combination of luck and omniscience.

Now there may be an inherent issue with the far-past catapult in that any success at changing the timeline will destroy the "present" with its large organized effort in place. Any arrival at all will appear in a different timeline not in their own past, so they cannot send multiple loads. They can send multiple *trys* though.  Each catapult seeds a new timeline and through repetition with variations on the plan the hope at least one of them turns out the way they intended.

For a limited load size and mass (your phone box isn't larger on the inside?) why send a single person w/carry-on baggage? Send nanotechnological robots or seeds for robots and infrastructure. If piloted also, the person is a dwarf (or has the body of a child) to make room for his stuff. That is a detail I've not seen in stories before.

If multiple loads *is* possible with the thread maintained to the new past only possible if they don't diverge (yet), set up the operation on the far side of the moon. The expedition is in shipping mode to receive as many loads as it can, and only after the thread is broken do they proceed with the mission.

Answer (score 18):

One of the fairly standard proofs of knowledge of future events is to have the information sealed in an envelope, and hand it to the person you are trying to convince with instructions to open it at the time of, or immediately after, the event.  The fact that the other person has it in their possession before an event happens is the proof that you knew it ahead of time.  Because they don't see the proof that you held such knowledge until after the event happened, they don't get to meddle with the flow of time, there by avoiding having them take actions that would change the outcomes.

If I were such a time traveler, I would probably pick sports as my proof.  Pick whatever major sport was in season for my target region and have a list of the final scores of each matchup.  Two weeks or so should give enough evidence to convince people that I knew what the results were going to be before the games were played.

Here is the catch though.  By demonstrating that time travel is a possibility, I am pretty much ensuring that someone is going to figure out how to do it.  I may try to mislead or derail their research efforts, but knowing that something is possible makes it pretty much inevitable that someone will eventually figure it out. Quite possibly sooner than they did in my original time line now that people are paying attention to it as a real possibility.

If one of my goals is to prevent time travel technology from being developed then I have to work a lot slower and more subtly.  I have to use my future knowledge to place myself in a position of influence, without making it obvious that I am from the future.

---

Edit in response to comments:

The way the scenario in the beginning of this plays out is that I select the individual I want to convince and come up with a way to approach them after doing a bit of preliminary work.  Once I have made contact I say something along the lines of "I have some important information for you, but you won't believe me if I tell you now.  Take this envelope, wait until Monday morning to open it, then email me at the address inside after you have verified the information it contains."

When you open the envelope Monday morning you find the scores at the end of each inning for all of the baseball games that occurred in the previous three days. You know the envelope has been in your possession for at least a full day prior to the first game on the list.  Now it is conceivable that I could have had a lucky guess on one or two games, or possibly found someone to bribe on a few more, but the probability of me having the outcome of every game across the nation for several days correct down to that level of detail is almost impossible.  (The information inside could really be anything, the key is that it is information about events that occurred after I gave it to you; It is inconceivable that I could have accurately predicted the data volume and level of detail without special knowledge; And it is equally inconceivable that I, or any organization supporting me, could have influenced the outcomes of all of those events.)

So obviously something special had to have happened.  Could I have tampered with the envelope after I gave it to you?  Possibly, but you have not seen me since, and I have made no further attempt to contact you.  Could I have been incredibly lucky? Sure, it is possible, but extremely unlikely.  And however I pulled it off, wouldn't it make you curious?

If I have a list of such contacts, and I work this same general scheme on each of them independently.  One or more of them is going to decide to reach out to me to find out what is going on.  Perhaps they do think I managed to pull a fast one on them, so offer to do it again when they can take some informed precautions.

One potential tripping point in this approach is keeping someone from opening their envelope early and trying to exploit the knowledge within.  If I am targeting current day, and particularly selecting tech savvy people as my targets, then I can encrypt the data, give them the encrypted file, and then wait to give them the key to decrypt it until after the events occur.

Comment: Such tricks as in your first paragraph might be seen as you being an illusionist instead of a time traveller.

Comment: @Mast  Possible but unlikely in the way I have envisioned this.  Updated my response with more details.

Comment: The envelope in the mark's possession is a trick already perfomed by showmen. The encryption is a good idea: you can see the cyphertext before the event and know that it was there all along.  The event itself contains the key.

Comment: Demonstrating time travel does not necessarily lead to its discovery. What if the time machine can only be built with exotic matter which arrives by comet impact in 2098, and cannot be produced through other means?

Comment: Demonstrating it would ensure people are looking at it with absolute certainty that it is possible. Perhaps the original time machine did need such an exotic material, but knowing something is possible pretty much guarantees someone will figure out how to do it.  Maybe they don't succeed until said exotic shows up, or maybe they figure out a substitute/synthetic, or maybe they find a totally different approach, particularly since our time traveler is trying to throw them off the technique he knows about.

Comment: I like the idea of encrypting the message.  Let's take it up a notch and use public key cryptography by both the traveler and the recipient.  The traveler encrypts the message with their private key; the recipient then encrypts the message with their _private_ key.  Now the message's accuracy is guaranteed up to the strength of the recipient's algorithm and key pair.

Answer (score 16):

The answer is Bitcoin.

Block chains are based on a cryptographic proof-of-work protocol: constructing one takes time and effort and processing power, but it's orders of magnitude easier to verify that they are correct.

So either get your hands on 100 years worth of block chain data, or use a 22nd century supercomputer to generate a brand new one, of a length sufficient to impress.  Load it up on as many antique terabyte drives as you can carry, get into the time-catapult, and find the nearest influential crypto enthusiast.

This scheme has several advantages: Unlike the 'Almanac', the locals can start verifying right away.  There's no risk of butterfly-effect: your block gain doesn't have to match anything from the 21st century, it just has to be internally consistent.  You're not bringing any useful technology or information back with you, just proof that you had it before you left.

Once a certain length of block chain is verified, the locals will have mathematically solid proof: Either you are a time-traveller, or you have access to more computing power than all of humanity combined, and have decided to use it to impersonate a time-traveller.  Either way, it's probably a good idea to listen to you.

A drawback of this solution is that it's highly technical.  Once you've convinced the global mathematics community, the NSA, and Reddit, you're on your own to convince the man-on-the-street.

Comment: Just to clarify on this one, you don't have to bring terabytes back with you.  All you need are the block headers, which will be very small in total even for a very long time into the future.  Or if you prefer, just bring a single header from 100+ years in the future when every individual hash in and of itself represents more computational work than the whole planet is capable of doing in 2015.  If you can provide a piece of data whose hash starts with 40 hexadecimal zeros, cryptographers worldwide will bow down and worship you.  Proof in 80 bytes!  You can even just memorise it before travel.

Comment: To add to @eMansipater 's comment, bringing only the headers would also help to avoid disrupting the Bitcoin network too much, which would respond to 100 years of blocks by accepting them all as valid immediately, greatly disrupting the current Bitcoin economy.

Answer (score 14):

It's actually quite easy.  Look at the stock market--this has been rejected by other posters on the basis that making a correct prediction will change the future.  The butterfly effect is certainly going to be an issue.  To protect against this you must make only one prediction and at a short range.

Have your time machine deliver you to the Oval Office, 10 minutes before the closing bell on Wall Street.  I would recommend minimal attire to minimize the nervousness of the Secret Service agents.

Arrive, hand the closest agent printout, tell him to keep it secure.  The printout looks like gibberish.  You then explain that you are a time traveler, come to warn of a disaster.  The printout you just provided is the closing prices for **every** actively traded stock.  There is a simple encoding scheme, even if it goes straight to a cryptographer they'll only have a few minutes to work on it--the crypto guys simply don't have time to bring their heavy guns to bear.

You make thousands of accurate predictions at once--they'll listen.  Popping in from thin air will also help.

Comment: The stock market's never been manipulated... oh, wait. They'll listen, -to your stock tips. This was *more* plausible before high frequency trading existed, where you'd of had to physically manipulate *things* opposed to 1's and 0's.

Comment: @Mazura Sure, you can manipulate the market--but nobody is going to be able to manipulate **all** the stocks at once.

Comment: Don't manipulate the market, get rich - at least that is what I've always wanted a time machine for :P.  Getting rich will get their attention.  When there's no evidence of insider trading or other illegal activity, it'll begin to lend weight to your claim.

Comment: They might well shoot you. But when they search your corpse, in your other pocket is the information you're warning them about which, once they'd decoded the stock prices and discovered them to be correct, they would hopefully also believe ;-)

Comment: A potential problem here is that someone might start trading crazily on purpose just to make sure your predictions are not accurate

Comment: Most of the complaints with this answer seem to hinge on the idea that the President of the U.S. and their Secret Service agents are going to deliberately try and sabotage stock market prices or get rich quickly in the ten minutes they have to react. Everybody could use more money, sure, but the government of a country isn't usually so strapped for cash that they'd prioritise that over figuring out the mystery of the teleporting future-man.

Answer (score 14):

Bring forth the bugs! - pick a ton of open-source projects, such as linux, and expose all the current security bugs (exposing one won't butterfly-contaminate the others, as the code is already written, saved, deployed on all sorts of machines, and won't auto-update to fix itself) - next, to prevent the ensuing hackfest, distribute the code that would be required to fix this newfound issue - the patches, fixes, etc. - you now have proven yourself as someone with credible world-saving abilities - people can speculate as to where this comes from, if necessary you could blackmail every single government or politician in the world (or just about anyone else) - basically choose things that have already occurred prior to the date that you wish to appear in, but have not yet been revealed to the public (think snowden leaks, only much larger, over more secret organizations, with the juicy stuff selected and chosen)

Comment: I like this.  There are lots of broken things that nobody even now knows are broken (Linux/BSD subsystems), and a number of broken things for which the details of the brokenness are not yet public (think Weiner).  Exposing (and fixing in one step) all of the fixable things and blackmailing all the (evil) politicians in one step makes for a great starting point.

Answer (score 12):

By request on the comment thread, I will expand on [rmoore's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/12395/353) and detail how the DNA analysis can prove the time traveler is indeed a descendant of his great-grandparents / grandparents.

[This page for a testing website](http://www.genetica.com/GeneticaWebV2.nsf/XGrandparentageDNATest.xsp) states that their rate of accuracy for grandparent DNA testing is 99,99%. If the grandparents are alive, the odds of the time traveler to NOT be the grandson of these people would be:

> 0.0001 ^ 4 = 0.000,000,000,000,000,1
>   1 in 1,000 trillion chances.

Since the amount of people that ever lived is estimated at 108 billions<sup>source [1](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/fire-in-the-mind/2013/08/11/how-many-people-ever-lived/#.VRCicI7F_fw) [2](http://www.prb.org/Publications/Articles/2002/HowManyPeopleHaveEverLivedonEarth.aspx) [3](http://www.strangerdimensions.com/2014/07/07/many-people-have-ever-lived-died/)</sup>, the explanation of time travel would be the accepted explanation by Occam's razor. The apple does not fall far from the tree. Also there is the paternal test for the Y chromosome (paternal grandfather) and the maternal test for the X chromosome (maternal grandparents) and the mitochondrial DNA testing (maternal grandmother).

> Unless his family has a huge recent history of incest, if the grandparents are already living, there would be no doubt he is a time traveler.

**But unfortunately, There is a great chance his grandparents are NOT yet born as of 2015.**

Lets assume they sent back a healthy indiviudal, on his prime. Lets also assume that his prime is at 25 years old, and that he was born when his parents were 25 years old, and his parents were born when his grandparents were 25 years old.

This would place the birthyears of our 2100 time traveler in 2075, his parents in 2050 and his grandparents in 2025. **His grandparents would be born only ten years-ish from now.** This would leave only his great-grandparents alive, in their teens. There is a trend of people having children at a higher age (with all that [egg freezing mania](http://www.businessinsider.com/apple-and-facebook-pay-women-to-freeze-eggs-2014-10) and stuff) so I think that this 25 years window is a safe assumption.

Now, great-grandparent dna testing is still mostly unheard of, but [looking at genealogy testing](http://genealogy.about.com/cs/geneticgenealogy/a/dna_tests.htm), we can get 95% proof that the time traveler belongs to the family line of his father's father's father. With autosomal DNA testing, he can be placed in the family tree of all of his eight great-grandparents (and since your grandparents have not yet been born, they are all alive by 2015). Now, unless they are close relatives (like several of those couples are cousins in love), a simple venn diagram would prove that the very existance of the time traveler would be impossible if he is not a time traveler. **Proof by contradiction.**

There is no other way our alleged time traveler could be part of eight completely unrelated family lines (and trace your mitochondrial DNA to a few and the Y-DNA to only one). Unless he is really the great-grandchildren of those eight families.

This one has less precision (still beyond reasonable doubt, but would *give a hook for the antagonists* to descredit our hero) than the grandparents (so the very skeptic may still be unsure, specially if some of the great-grandparents were related), but with some more info about the future, the time traveler would succeed.

---

Picture the adventures of a time traveler trying to convince eight teens to do agree to DNA testing, all the while dodging the evil organization and attempting to avoid doomsday.

Also for bonus kicks, he tries to get the matchups of his great-grandparents right, while the teen hormones attempt to negate his family line.

Comment: The problem is very similar to that of convicting criminals based on DNA matches, and I think you are committing the same error that was infamously committed by many such trials.

Answer (score 11):

A reverse-compatible (USB3.0) hard drive full of the most expensive movies, pop songs, selected news media, YouTube, selected Internet, and perhaps selected scientific publications from the year after you arrive for several decades into the future. You're either from the future, or from an alternate Earth future.

However, proving you're from the future is probably a lot easier than gaining the trust of authorities, and avoiding getting abused by people who decide to behave badly when tempted by the potential wealth/power they might think they could hoard to themselves if they captured you.

So, you might want to bring a device that would let you make anonymous undetectable broadcasts, as well. And other things that might help with your personal security and well-being.

Comment: Yay, and everyone can save the money to actually produce this stuff now.

Answer (score 11):

Have the person you're trying to convince write a long letter, and post it to you (or your Grandfather). You'll receive it in the future.

Then you produce the envelope out of your pocket, open it and reveal the letter!

Comment: This does not work. If you went back in time to change something, then you must assume that the time travel mechanics at work send you into an alternate timeline (otherwise you can't change anything and there's no point in the trip, let alone in proving your story once you get to the past). And if you are in an alternate timeline, then you're never going to receive that letter.

Comment: It works assuming the "you" from this time-line also makes the trip, and as such becomes the "you" that's here now, and as such, has the letter.

Answer (score 10):

A variant of the lottery numbers ploy: bring some other information which is top secret right now, but part of the historical archives in the future. That should get the immediate attention of government agencies if the time traveler phones them.

Comment: Nice. Solves the butterfly effect, which is an issue with the lottery. Might just get you arrested though, and leaks can happen without time travel.

Comment: This is great if the only people you plan to tell are the CIA. Also if you don't plan on returning to your time machine any time soon.

Comment: @corsiKa the Q states that its a time catapult. He did not bring it with him.

Comment: Wait.  So, Snowden is a time traveler and not some guy that got access to files that the (supposed to be transparent) government didn't want to get access to?  I'm so confused.

Answer (score 9):

It's easier to think about what type of thing you'd bring back 100 years to the *past* that would convince people you are from the "future" (IE, Now).

Our future man could easily find out what hasn't been invented yet this year and take a product from his time back with him to our time to prove his authenticity.  Demonstrating his technical prowess with an unusual device that does not exist anywhere else in the world should be sufficient proof.

If we were to compare it to travelling from now to 100 years ago, all anyone would have to do is take their smartphone out of their pocket and play some music.  Not only would the music be strange to the listener, it would be a remarkable technology in itself - even without the ability to connect to a wireless network (a problem with any technology dependent on future infrastructure).

For our man from the future, his handheld matter converter that turns common paper into hot dogs should do nicely.

Comment: I think this falls under: "would be likely to just look like someone working in his garage made a breakthrough in some field, and that's pretty cool and all, but obviously it doesn't prove he's from the future."

Comment: @Octopus No. Even in our era, it costs an awful lot of money to make a single processor/phone/etc.: we can only buy them cheap because they're made in bulk. To develop the technology and make one would be phenomenally expensive in 1900. Maybe a few large governments could have done it collaboratively, but I doubt it. It's not garage stuff.

Comment: I believe in a future where hot dogs don't exist.

Comment: Well if it were me going back 100 years ... How about 1960s trawler sonar schematics. Should beat the tar out of WW1 sonar.

Comment: @Joshua Only if you can also provide the micro circuitry and mechanical guidance to build them and implement them on 1920s era warships.  In other words, I hope you're a Doctor of Engineering, or at the very least telecommunications.

Comment: @Zibbobz: I named 1960s because they still used individual transistors, etc. Should not be too hard to adapt to tubes.

Answer (score 8):

I'm surprised nobody has stated the obvious: bring back a sports almanac that shows the result of every major sports event until the end of the century.

Comment: Enter Biff Tannen...

Comment: Unfortunately, that fails on the speed criterion, and also risks the butterfly effect, whereby the more distant scores change because of your presence. As for just reading off the first few results: plenty of gamblers work out the correct scores for a few games. Not a bad idea though.

Comment: Can you [edit] to explain how this satisfies the time constraints in the question?

Comment: @GKFX - but the Almanac would change as the future results change!

Comment: @GKFX How does this fail the speed criterion? In this scenario (impending disaster) more distant scores don't matter -- all you need to do is prove immediately that you're actually from the future. Any scores more than a couple months away are irrelevant.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Which specific time constraints, can you elaborate?

Comment: @markcoatsworth I was referring to #2 in the question; sorry for being unclear.  He wants to get his credentials as a time-traveler established quickly, so waiting for a year (or even a season) of games to play out might take too long.  Maybe you can suggest why that needn't take very long?  (I've never looked inside a sports almanac, BTW, so don't know how much they cover.)

Comment: @markcoatsworth It was the word "century" that made me say about the speed criterion. If it worked, a year's worth of results would be sufficient and fast enough, as you've argued.

Answer (score 8):

Send two payloads into the past. First send a probe (or even the time travellers luggage) to March 30. After making sure the probe is sent, then send the traveller to March 1. All the time traveller has to do is tell news agencies that his probe/luggage and maybe artifacts from the future will arrive on March 30 at a specific time and place.

For a real world example of how people react to a time traveller you should also check out the John Titor story. A time traveller revealed himself on internet bulletin boards during the years 2000 and 2001. Caused quite a stir after he posted pictures of his time machine.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Titor

from http://www.abovetopsecret.com/forum/thread62046/pg1

> excerpt: This is a picture taken in the fall of 2035 during my
>   training. It shows my instructor beaming a handheld laser outside the
>   vehicle during operation. The beam is being bent by the gravitational
>   field produced outside the vehicle by the distortion unit.

[image]

from http://www.strangerdimensions.com/2013/02/04/john-titor-the-man-with-the-machine/
[image]

For your time traveller it might also be prudent to remember that doomsday predictions can also attract the wrong kind of audience (ufo and doomsday believers) which could be detrimental when he is trying to prove his authenticity.

Comment: Presumably, everybody also smokes cigars white fat-arming it out the window in 2035 and black and white grainy photography is in vogue.

Comment: Perhaps in 2035 it will be hip to make your photos look like the first generation of camera phones? Much like it's hip now to make your photos look like 1960s Polaroids?

Comment: And he got the idea from reading it here... dun dun dun.

Answer (score 5):

What if the time travel resulted in some form of semi-violent catastrophe, or publicly visible entering of our time?

Since we do not know what time travel will do to our reality this might be feasible. If I knew time was of the essence, I'd make sure I'd enter with a big BANG, to get this identification process out of the way ASAP... Of course this might also result in being arrested and potentially tortured to get information.

But lets assume, that the above doesn't happen, and if somehow during this process the Eiffel tower got sucked up in some space time void, or for that matter any other major publicly visible entrance event occurs in a manner that it unknown to us, leaving only our hero as the sole survivor... people will notice.

Comment: That doesn't establish time-travel as the cause, though; that just demonstrates that something weird happened -- aliens, terrorists, satanists, whatever.

Comment: @MonicaCellio... true, but as I've said. "Since we do not know what time travel will do to our reality this might be feasible." At least it will draw attention... which was one of the sub points. If I had to see some gigantic space time portal thing or whatever it is, rip open... Id take whoever created / came out of it's word for what caused it. So the caveat is that everyone sees this event playing out.

Comment: No-go.  In Continuum, some unfortunate bridge took damage repeatedly from being the end point of time traveler arrivals.  The cops never really noticed except to make sure it wasn't a bombing.  Some person at the arrival point would be treated as time-local, maybe crazy, but certainly not special (a time traveler).

Comment: @killermist... is the op writing/questioning as part of the Continuum universe? I mean I've never seen it myself, but I'd assume there are multiple realities, even when things like time travel comes into play not only one solution is feasible.

Comment: I was using it as an example.  "What if the time travel resulted in some form of semi-violent catastrophe...?"  Check.  Did anyone notice anything other than a "bombing" with no bomb debris?  Nope.  Trying to pin that to "I'm a time traveler" totally doesn't work.

Comment: @killermist.. again, that's just one variation of this situation playing out. Whose to say in every reality people will react the same?

Answer (score 5):

The "standard" solution to this is to predict the future.

The most straightforward version would be to print out and bring along stock market data for some time following your intended arrival. It is widely believed that the movements of the stock market are impossible to predict precisely, so consistent success at this would be quite convincing. And, if everyone is still incredulous, you could just leverage your information to make a fortune and then simply pay them to do what you want. If you want the time traveler to not have this disproportionate power, you could instead give him a one way hash of the market figures - that way he would not be able to predict what the value will be, but it will be possible to determine whether he had access to the future value at any point.

Alternatives include guessing lottery numbers, weather, sports competition outcomes, and so on. All of these have the drawback of being chaotic, and so if your universe takes a "butterfly effect" approach to time travel, the simple presence of the traveler may disrupt these events and render predictions useless.

To solve this issue, you can try bringing back large scale historical events, which would take more than a flap of a butterfly's wings to alter. For instance, presumably a person traveling to 1913 would have a lot of trouble preventing a world war in early 20th century, even if they did manage to save Archduke Ferdinand. The drawback here is that major historical events may be predicted, and people may ascribe the prediction to extraordinarily sharp deductive powers rather than future knowledge.

Lastly, you could bring back information that was already past at the time of arrival, but would not be widely known until much after. For instance, [an important shipwreck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uluburun_shipwreck) was discovered by chance in 1982. If you traveled to 1975 with a map showing the location of the wreck, locating it would be an extraordinary feat. Some could accuse you of stumbling upon the wreck yourself, and trying to spin it into a time travel story, but if you do this for many shipwrecks (or other artifacts) around the globe, that theory will become quite weak. Besides archeological finds, you could go back with information that was a very well kept secret at the time. The nice thing about this strategy is that even if some chaotic process ruins the future you are trying to predict as proof, the past would not be affected (granted this assertion is dubious in a universe where traveling backwards in time is possible) and your proof is safe.

Answer (score 5):

Actual "proof" of being from the future is pointless: the goal is to convince people, and few people can be convinced of something in violation with their belief system, regardless of "proof".

How many well established scientific facts are being ignored on a daily basis?

People smoke and eat unhealthy foods, even though it is fairly well established that smoking massively increases risks of disease and death. They drink, take drugs and drive. We still run and build coal fired plants even though the environmental consequences are catastrophic....

Think of the long list of patently insane behaviors people have on this planet. No matter how thoroughly something is proven, you will find people to dismiss it entirely with no evidence.

Using "proof" to convince people to do something is sadly not an effective way to get them to do things.

Suppose someone were to give **you** abundant proof of an upcoming catastrophe... what do you do next? Who do you contact and how would you go about convincing the people in power and the concerned population to follow your orders?

Proving one is from the future is not just impossible, it's also pointless. If the goal is to convince specific people not to take a specific path, proof of time travel isn't going to do the trick. Better come up with a carrot, a stick or both to get these people moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

People seem to be thinking small in terms of "data points required to not just be a charlatan." Rather than a single lottery or a series of sporting games, why not just correctly "predict" the full intraday pricing on a second-by-second basis of, say, 1,000 equity options ?

- Stock option prices are governed by stochasticity, i.e. any given 
  moment a stock option's price is just as likely to go up as down.
- You may be able to rig a lottery or a sporting match or two, but rigging an entire open market is ... unfeasible.

So that's 1,000 stock option volatilities * 28,800 seconds in a trading day = 288,000,000 basically coin flips you accurately predicted.

Comment: Good idea! Welcome to the site. However, the amount of time needed to display your information so that it can be proven to have existed before that day is a problem. And then you consider the butterfly effect..

Comment: Unless your arrival creates even a simple sonic boom, but at worst a small tremor.  Countless investors decide to do something different.  You're back down to 50% success rate pretty rapidly.

Answer (score 2):

I would say bring news videos from the future, near future, and of the events, needed, make sure that the news anchors shown are very prominent ones that would be hard to miss

Answer (score 1):

I'd just write down the lottery winners for the near future before it's announced, hand them in to the people I want to convince, in an envelope, and ask them to verify after they're announced. After 2 or 3 times, they should believe.

Comment: Honestly, I still would find it more plausible that someone had rigged the lottery than had traveled back in time.

Comment: And yet, you'd be satisfied the lottery were rigged but the rigger decided to use that to prove time travel as a hoax, instead of taking his portion of a $500M jackpot.

Comment: I agree with Dan D, you're trying to convince someone who is absolutely positive that time-travel is impossible, so any other possibility, no matter how crazy or unlikely is still more plausible than time travel. Besides, it's quite likely that if you're in a position where you can rig the lottery, then you couldn't claim the jackpot for whatever reason. (e.g. you'd be charged with fraud and have the winnings taken off you anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Have someone ask this question, and then post this answer.

Hello all, I am from the future. I come from 2345 AD. We are looking for test subjects for our experiments, and we've been running short. All volunteers will be paid generously, using future cash, or, as we call it, "rubber". I can't say any more or this will cause a ripple effect. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone living today would really be drawn by money which will only start to be valid three hundred years from now.

Comment: Valid point, but we are offering for our test subjects to remain in the future after experimentation has been performed on them for exactly 1,750 months. We will pay at minimum 350 gigarubbers; with that you could buy over 32 Nano Battery Blimps (the real stuff, from Ford, not those crummy Micro Battery Balloons that only last 10 years) or 184 CPT-96 neural memory upgrades!

Comment: Can you explain how that would persuade people that you're from the future, rather than just some kook who thinks he is?

Comment: Can you explain how you are not my nemesis from the future, who also came back in time to try to convince everyone that I am not from the future? I assure you, your miserable plan will fail, and your faction will not take control of this galaxy! Go back to the Andromeda Galaxy, and leave us humanoids alone!

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done. If you show me advanced technology, I will assume that you come from a society with advanced technology. If you make predictions of the future, I will assume you have advanced technology that can make those predictions. You might be able to convince specific individual people by targeting a message specifically to them, but any general future predicting or technology marvels are easier to explain without time travel.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that the time machine can be used multiple times:

**Step 1:** Get some attention. Go to the pentagon, try to break the security and fail. This way some official people will hear what you have to say.

**Step 2:** Threaten them: "In 4 hours a bomb is gonna explode at some precise place." This place will be heavily watched after this.

**Step 3:** Send something from the future at this precise place and time. It can be anything, the important thing is that people see that an object has appeared out of thin air.

From here on out, people should listen to you a lot more.

Comment: While they'll have to agree that you know something that they don't, if you try to earn their trust by lying to them, you're likely not going to get the trust you think you'll get.

Comment: @Neil He's not only lying to them, he's *threatening* them. This plan is a great way to get yourself sent to a secret prison where you are interrogated with "enhanced" methods.

Comment: This just proves that you know the timeline for when something is going to appear.  It would be just as (or more?) likely that the officials decide you are engaged in espionage and supported by a group that has made a break through in matter transportation in our own time.  Your prediction has to be something that is obviously out of your control, and couldn't have been arranged before you presented your claim.

Comment: I'd agree with breaking in, but is there a better way to gain their trust beyond a bomb threat?

Comment: This answer does indirectly bring up the point that you might also want to think about how to avoid being a victim of nasty human behavior. Some people might want to lock you up and use you as their personal future-predictor.

Answer (score 0):

The iPad one is interesting, but "theoretically" someone could have had a secret processing plant employing one million people, underground, working independently for 50 years, funded by an alien race if necessary. Anyway, the physics of an iPad was known in 1995, if not the mechanics.

So - what about simply predicting a solar flare? Or better still - bring a photo.

Comment: Read the word "Photoshop"

Answer (score 0):

If this traveler were time travelling 'within one universe' instead of jumping to other 'local' universes in different states of relative co-existance, you immediate destroy the universe you 'jump from'.

If you are going for the more linear classic approach to time travel, the traveler could bring back something which co-exists in 2100 which is iconic and priceless to boot, but most of all unique - and dare the objector to prove falsehood.

Depending on how many universes you believe in (if any), you could tell them to damage it and then watch the corresponding damage occur.  Go further and destroy the item and poof! It disappears.  But if so, then so did the traveler's effort obtain it, because it never existed to bring back... but only because he went back with it was it destroyed in the first place.  I know causality is not meant to be an issue, but it is!  So I think you probably destroy the universe by going back in time at all - at the very least the chances of doing so rise geometrically (towards tangent 90, or something, per unit of observable time, probably).  Regardless, he rips wide open the future, which has or has not happened.  Perhaps he's beaten the odds?  And of course he must, because he exists in the first place!

So I'd wonder whether this time traveler.... is there a future ahead of him with time travel?

My personal feelings are that future events are so intrinsically sensitive to present conditions that one irrevocably determine the outcome of the universe simply by doing nothing.  Hell, I am just part of the universe playing itself out as intended, am I not?  And if I never learned to tie my shoelaces until I was six, instead of five, for example - stuff like 9/11 wouldn't have happened.

Which is absurd surely?  OR IS IT?  Time travelling, and a pre-determined future (whilst the chances of one existing are non-zero, is definitely, definitely not our realm.

But yeah OK, causality is not an issue - if he were travelling linearly backwards and wanted proof, an object he could bring back might be something like a radioactive vial with a unique signature of something which has shown measurable decay.  Perhaps also the traveler possesses a residual charge of something, or has a little extra amount of 'entangled' particles in all his orbits.  A quantum signature.

/BLURT

Answer (score 0):

Bring a future weapon. If I know humans, we continue to grow better at killing each other. Why a weapon? Well, if you are going to the past to change the course of history, that means you are interrupting the plans of powerful people, leaders (upsetting them at least). Once they are on to your motivation, they will try to silence/terminate you even if they are convinced you are from the future. I would even bring a doomsday device as an insurance policy. If the future is so bad that you were sent to the past to alter it, would it really be that bad to destroy the world in the past if your mission failed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to prove that you're from the future without showing off your TARDIS. Yes, you can predict forty trillion data points accurately, but we as a species are far too skeptical. However, this is meant to be more constructive than a simple "No" so here we go.

Given the rate at which science is advancing, it's fairly safe to say that new fields of study will pop up in a hundred years time. Instead of showing off massive advances in robotics, or matter manipulation, show off a new kind of thing, as alien as my cell phone is to Socrates. Most people will still have a little bit of doubt in their heads, so reveal the quadrillion data points ya got. Give stellar maps that show galaxies and planets that are too far away for the light to have reached us yet. Do all the other things these answers say. Before you leave for the past, study all kinds of stuff; biology, robotics, computing, chemistry. Make sure you can answer any question a scientist can throw at you.

Answer (score 0):

We're talking about around 100 years of history and rather than proof, I see credibility as a bigger problem, proof is worthless without it.

Assuming there is no language barrier, even if the protagonist were speaking the same language as the people around him it would be language separated by around 100 years or gradual change. Look at how laughable films from the 1950s look now then invert the context that 1950s language, attitudes and social mores are the norm and the observer is in a minority of 1.

Credibility issues are common to history documentaries. They use the viewer's "modern" perspective to frame events in a way that conforms to biases. A quick glance at 20th century newsreels containing "white man's burden" topics underlines what I'm driving at, all of them from less than 80 years ago. The concept of "modern" is very nebulous and changes from generation to generation.

History is not an absolute - it is simply an interpretation of events and the present is a huge jumble of events with future implications interpreted by the conventional wisdom of that time.

So even with future hindsight, the future time-traveller would have to choose several events that the people of that time and geographic location would care enough about to want to have their preconceptions challenged, and would likely fall foul of any powers that had vested interests in seeing an outcome to fruition. Lets say traveling back in time to stop the birth of Islamic State cells, a little shy of 20 years ago, would pit the protagonist against a hawkish American government policy intent on invading Iraq using a "for us or agin us" approach to anything seen as being critical, and using kidnapping and detainment in Guantanamo Bay against people they deemed to be "enemy combatants".

Answer (score -2):

If your time traveller wants to prove they came from the future, you don't send a man you send a woman instead. Because she will be wearing clothes of her own future time. But just to be sure, she carries an extra set of her underwear. Why an extra set of her underwear? you chime. The answer's quite simple. No garments change as much as women's underwear.

Think how much difference there is in the styles, construction, and materials of underwear between now and, say, sixty years ago. Any woman in 1950 being shown a set of contemporary undergarments would immediately recognise how much better they were and wouldn't take much convincing they came from the future.

Using underwear as your future person litmus test doesn't lead to any problems with reverse engineering or likely causality violations. Also it's simple and readily portable.

Since a picture is worth a thousand words then picture [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28ZY-8l6CZg) and for good measure [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-lFrs8UwEs) too.

Comment: That wouldn't work, unless the underwear is some super-science weirdness. A difference in style and make-up won't say "future" to anyone. Also 1950's woman would think modern women's underwear utterly promiscuous.

Comment: @DomineSatanas. "Some super-science weirdness" like force-field body-suits? There are sufficient material differences between current underwear and that of the 1950s. Besides you underestimate women of the 1950s. Try the links to YouTube in my last paragraph, that might change your mind.

Comment: Well, friend downvoter, pity you didn't explain your objection instead simply downvoting. Friend DomineSatanas, at least, expressed his disagreement. He and I could have discussed our viewpoints. We could have too. Hopefully we still might. Ah well you can't have everything.

Comment: I would, but it's just so ridiculous. Every time I type out a response it comes off too hostile.

Comment: Goodness! Another downvote! Pity there isn't comment to explain why there is an objection. Such a simple concepts really. Nothing indicates progress like developments in feminine intimate apparel. Something adults with a reasonable amount of life experience can appreciate and understand. Well friend downvoter, if you'd like to explain your objections, I'd be happy to hear them.

Answer (score -6):

Get the largest prime number found from the future.

Now 2<sup>74,207,281</sup> − 1 is the largest prime number. If he is from future it will be larger than this number.

So he can prove he is from future.

Comment: *How* does that prove he’s from the future?  I would counter that he just found a new record prime.  I’d say that’s rather poor supporting evidence, since even a significantly larger new record could be explained by having a large base of spare computing power, new algorithms, improced number theory to suggest smaller areas to look in, or a bit of luck.

Comment: @JDługosz question says 2100 , so prime number from that time will many times  magnitude higher than current  value ..

Comment: Still, “he invented a quantum computer” is a more likely hypothosis than “he’s a time traveller.”

Comment: @JDługosz i doubt a single person will invent quantum computer ,,if he does , that single person will be capable of inventing time machine then ...

Comment: That's the plot of a Crichton novel.  But really, I doubt any single person can invent time travel.  So, your same argument works both ways, and doesn’t **prove** anything.

Comment: ※ See my edit.  You can view the markup to see how it’s done.

Comment: Hi there, as @JDługosz mentioned quantum computing is a very likely hypothesis, as for example checking for primes will be possible in [polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor's_algorithm). The already big gap between two largest primes will make a big jump at this point. You would need to prove that quantum computing on such a scale is not possible in the time you arrive to prove you are from the future. Just giving people the number won't work as everyone will just say "You invented quantum computing", while you can only say "No, I'm from the future", which is not convincing.

Comment: @Secespitus in 2100 , the magnitude of the prime number will be of course higher than what will be  found  quantum computing (if invented from present) if person has really bigger prime number than predicted from quantum number of course that person is from future..

Comment: « of course that person is from future.» That is **not proof**. Nobody beleives that conclusion.  He got it from advanced extraterrestrials or found the lost records of Atlantis.  There are other hypotheses and you can’t just say “of course” to constitute a proof.

Comment: There is the problem of who the time traveller has convince. Considerably he must persuade people in 2015 to prevent a catastrophe this will mean governments & government officials. Higher prime numbers may not prove convincing to them. Mathematicians might be impressed. As suggested there are many alternatives to source of this higher prime without involving time travel. It's an ingenious concept, but not, alas, convincing.

Comment: @a4android i was thinking magnitude of the prime number will be very higher after 100years ,,like higher than what we can predict using current technology ...

Comment: You're right by 2100 they should have found higher prime numbers, but that of and in itself doesn't prove someone is a time traveller. As @JDługosz there are other possibilities. My suspicion is that a time traveller will need and probably have multiple proofs they come from the future.