How long for a localized time loop to notice outside universe changing?
Given...
A sphere 2000 au large centered on the center of the sun stuck in a time loop of one day.
Question: How long would it take before astronomers would be able to confidently tell that the outside universe was in the relative future?

This is not a worldbuilding question. It’s speculation about the actions and decisions of in world characters.

if questions like https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13503/how-do-you-prove-youve-been-to-the-future?rq=1 are able to asked, regarding when something, COULD be possible, I think my question is reasonable.

That question should be closed as well. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Oops I meant to link, https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/146061/how-long-would-it-take-for-people-to-notice-a-mass-disappearance?rq=1 , the one I linked before is a how, not how long till.

Same issues with it too. This isn’t a question about your world but a story set inside it.

Hello @NovusPendragon. Sorry for the rocky start, this being only your second question. The reason it's Too Story-Based is that you've not explained the details of what it means to have a localized time loop. You see, that's not a universally understood, scientifically based thing. Time loops are pure fiction, and that means you need to tell us how they work. Alices_and_Bobs' answer made a good point (one that should have kept him/her from answering the question): if everything within the sphere resets, including light and gravity, then they'll never know. ... (*Continued*)

... You see, you need to explain to us how your time loop works, especially what happens at the boundary of the sphere. What happens when radiation, matter, and gravity hits it from the outside? What happens when it's hit from the inside? What happens to the boundary itself? There isn't any science, it's pure speculation and imagination - specifically your imagination. So it would have made more sense to close your question as Needs More Details. You might consider using the Sandbox until you get the hang of how it works here.

I will understand the question as being about when and how astronomers with current technology and equipment etc will be likely to discover it. The outcome depends on what you meant by time loop and exactly how it works (and whether FTL technology is possible and whether there exists alien civilizations that may discover such technology one day), but in most scenarios I think they will never be able to discover it.
If everything in the sphere resets every day, including light and gravitational waves from outside: This essentially means information and physical effects from outside the sphere will never reach our solar system again. Doesn't matter if you meant diameter or radius of the sphere. Basically there's no reason for anyone to suspect anything different, as no one will remember and every iteration will be as a new day, and no new discovery(even if FTL is possible) would change anything in such a short amount of time, a least from the human's side.
Even if alien civilizations beyond would discover the anomaly and perhaps arrive to take advantage of the resources when most other stars in the universe burn out(and are lucky enough to not lose all their probes in a reset), they wouldn't be able to affect the humans unless they have FTL technology, and they can't safely settle inside the sphere anyway. There's not much sunlight they can get from 2000 AU away from the sun, and the only way it could be really useful to them is if some large object like a comet happens to move outside of the sphere that day - it would be hilarious to think some alien colony would depend on a supply of fresh comets from our solar system every day; perhaps they can eventually build a huge oversized Dyson sphere with that extra material. If they explore the sphere thoroughly out of curiosity, with infinite resources and time, they will eventually discover Earth and humans and might possibly tell them about the phenomenon. It's too hard to estimate how many days that would take even if it happens but it's must be a truly astronomical number. (And it might never happen if there are no sufficiently close and advanced alien civilizations to discover it before all other stars outside burn out)
If only people's memory is magically kept across iterations, but everything else physical will be reset: not much difference from the previous case. People will soon think it's a time loop of the whole observable universe because there won't be any physical evidence to the contrary. Without some unforeseen huge scientific breakthrough that could miraculously be implemented within one day that removes the speed of light restriction, I think it's still impossible unless lucky aliens with FTL technology happen to be there to tell us.
If instead you meant everything will be reset except for light and other effects coming from outside the sphere, so that magically the waves from outside would keep moving inside the sphere as normal even as everything else resets(from a physics point of view it's very strange but intuitively it makes some sense): 2000 AU is about 11.5 light days, so after 12 or 6-ish days (depending on if it's the radius or diameter of the sphere) it's possible to notice something wrong astronomically. But how wrong depends on how the reset actually works and requires some calculation. For example if the location but not velocity of the sphere is reset using the reference frame of the galaxy center, the sun and everything around it will soon move out of its orbit in the galaxy, and every other star's location from Earth's point of view would be off very quickly. If the sphere always follows the sun's reference frame, the stars should appear to continue behaving as normal, but the planets' motion would reset. If people's memory are also magically kept, they will probably first notice the planets and moon are being reset while other stars are not, and should deduce that it's only our solar system being reset in a few days at most. If people's memory are not carried over, they would observe stars appearing like they should be in the future, and astronomers would be much more uncertain about what's going on as they would try to find some conventional explanation and their first reaction would not reasonably be that we are in a time loop (and people may not care as much as they would if they had kept the memories), and it may take weeks or months to gather evidence of exactly which objects are "in the future" before they can conclude the problem is within the solar system.
Caveats: things could be different if the definitions of day and AU might change. Currently AU is formally defined as a specific length of meters which is defined using the speed of light so it's probably not gonna change, but there are multiple ways to define a day, some dependent on astronomical relations between Earth and the Sun or other bodies. If "day" is defined loosely, and the time loop period depends on it, it may be possible to change the time loop length by changing Earth's rotation speed or relative motion to the sun or some star, perhaps eventually allowing light from outside the sphere to reach the Earth in time.
